# How can I prevent somebody who has my google-services.json from accessing my project?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how can I prevent somebody who has my `google-services.json` file associated with one of my Firebase Firestore projects from accessing my project.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way unless you create a new Firebase project.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to create a new google-service.json after you make any changes to console,
it will be automatically created,
you just need to download it from

**settings -> Project settings -> select your package/bundle-id -> click the download icon**
[image]

Comment: I had shared my existing google-services.json to someone, so wanted to re-generate, so that they don't have access to my firebase firestore services. That is the reason I want to re-generate it.

Comment: @xpetta Please add that information to your question, which seems to be "How can I prevent somebody who has my `google-services.json` from accessing my project?" I also recommend reading about [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). :)

Comment: Thank you so much @FrankvanPuffelen for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't there's a way to you can change those credentials for the same project. Even if you delete that app and recreate it in Firebase project, it'll change the `mobilesdk_app_id` only. Creating a new project maybe the only way to get a completely new `google-services.json`

I'm not sure which SSH keys you are referring to but if you are just re-configuring your application then you can visit https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general and then select the app name you are looking for. You'll have an option to download `google-services.json` there. The rest of configuration process should remain the same.